# Get child Node of another Node, given node name

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML like this:

```
<documentslist>
  <document>
    <docnumber>1</docnumber>
    <docname>Declaration of Human Rights</docname>
    <aoo>lib</aoo>
  </document>
  <document>
    <docnumber>2</docnumber>
    <docname>Fair trade</docname>
    <aoo>lib</aoo>
  </document>
  <document>
    <docnumber>3</docnumber>
    <docname>The wars for water</docname>
    <aoo>lib</aoo>
  </document>
  <!-- etc. -->
</documentslist>
```

I have this code:

```
//XML parsing
Document docsDoc = null;
try {
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    docsDoc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlWithDocs)));
}
catch(ParserConfigurationException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
catch(SAXException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
//retrieve document elements
NodeList docs = docsDoc.getElementsByTagName("document");

if (docs.getLength() > 0){
    //print a row for each document
    for (int i=0; i<docs.getLength(); i++){
        //get current document
        Node doc = docs.item(i);
        //print a cell for some document children
        for (int j=0; j<columns.length; j++){
            Node cell;
            //print docname
            cell = doc.getElementsByTagName("docname").item(0); //doesn't work
            System.out.print(cell.getTextContent() + "\t");
            //print aoo
            cell = doc.getElementsByTagName("aoo").item(0); //doesn't work
            System.out.print(cell.getTextContent() + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But, as you know **`Node` hasn't got `getElementsByTagName` method**... Only `Document` has it. But I can't do `docsDoc.getElementsByTagName("aoo")`, because it will return me all `<aoo>` nodes, not only the one existing in the `<document>` node I'm inspecting.

How could I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Google or Wikipedia: recursion.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If the `Node` is not just any node, but actually an `Element` (it could also be e.g. an attribute or a text node), you can cast it to `Element` and use `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Element actually extends Node and not the other way around. I wouldn't rely on Node always being an Element, make sure to cast after checking the type of Node using instanceof like Yeameen suggested. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html

Answer (score 27):

Check if the `Node` is a Dom `Element`, cast, and call `getElementsByTagName()`

```
Node doc = docs.item(i);
if(doc instanceof Element) {
    Element docElement = (Element)doc;
    ...
    cell = doc.getElementsByTagName("aoo").item(0);
}
```

Comment: if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE )

Answer (score 6):

You should read it recursively, some time ago I had the same question and solve with this code:

```
public void proccessMenuNodeList(NodeList nl, JMenuBar menubar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        proccessMenuNode(nl.item(i), menubar);
    }
}

public void proccessMenuNode(Node n, Container parent) {
    if(!n.getNodeName().equals("menu"))
        return;
    Element element = (Element) n;
    String type = element.getAttribute("type");
    String name = element.getAttribute("name");
    if (type.equals("menu")) {
        NodeList nl = element.getChildNodes();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu(name);

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
            proccessMenuNode(nl.item(i), menu);

        parent.add(menu);
    } else if (type.equals("item")) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(name);
        parent.add(item);
    }
}
```

Probably you can adapt it for your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
//xn=list of parent nodes......                
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{                                           
    foreach (XmlNode child in xn.ChildNodes) 
    {
        if (child.Name.Equals("name")) 
        {
            name = child.InnerText; 
        }
        if (child.Name.Equals("age"))
        {
            age = child.InnerText; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please comment about the highlight of your code that will help to solve the issue. That will help to make it more easily understandable.

Comment: This does not look like Java.